# ¿Cómo definir las columnas de un crosstable de forma dinámica? VER MODIFICACION

Tags: postgresql, pivot

**ANTERIOR**
Estoy intentando realizar un ejemplo de crosstable, para luego implementarlo en tablas mas complejas, y me surge una duda/problema.

Como ejemplo me he creado estas tablas con estos datos:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

    CREATE TABLE meses(
    id serial,
    mes VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(1,'Enero');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(2,'Febrero');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(3,'Marzo');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(4,'Abril');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(5,'Mayo');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(6,'Junio');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(7,'Julio');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(8,'Agosto');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(9,'Septiembre');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(10,'Octubre');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(11,'Noviembre');
    INSERT INTO meses VALUES(12,'Diciembre');


    CREATE TABLE ventas(
    id serial,
    año int,
    mes int REFERENCES meses(id)NOT NULL, 
    total int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(1,2007, 1, 1000);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(2,2007, 2, 1500);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(3,2007, 7, 500);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(4,2007, 11, 1500);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(5,2007, 12, 2000);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(6,2008, 1, 1000);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(7,2009, 5, 2500);
    INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(8,2009, 9, 800);
```

Luego lanzo el crosstable, con las cabeceras de las columnas fijas (meses)

```
    SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT año, mes, total FROM ventas ORDER BY 1',
    'SELECT id FROM meses m'
    ) AS (
    año int, 
    "Enero" int, "Febrero" int, "Marzo" int, "Abril" int, "Mayo" int, "Junio" int, "Julio" int, "Agosto" int, "Septiembre" int, "Octubre" int, "Noviembre" int, "Diciembre" int
    );
```

[image: crosstable estatico]

Hasta aqui, todo correcto, pero la duda me surge, si quiero pasar las cabeceras del crosstable(los parametros del AS() del crosstable), a través de un select a la tabla meses, en ved de escribirlos fijos.

Algo como:

```
    SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT año, mes, total FROM ventas ORDER BY 1',
    'SELECT id FROM meses m'
    ) AS (
    año int, 
    (select mes from meses)  **que cree una linea por mes de tabla meses**
    );
```

¿Es posible realizarlo? ¿Se le pueden pasar a traves de un select, las cabeceras del crosstable?

Gracias.

** ********** ** **ULTIMA MODIFICACION**
**EDICION TRAS RESPUESTA DE Patricio:**

Pasándolo a caso REAL, no lo he conseguido.

Tengo estas tablas:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grosor_tubo (
                    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                    grosor NUMERIC (12,2) UNIQUE NOT NULL
                );


                INSERT INTO grosor_tubo VALUES(1,'1.00');
                INSERT INTO grosor_tubo VALUES(2,'1.20');
                INSERT INTO grosor_tubo VALUES(3,'1.50');
                INSERT INTO grosor_tubo VALUES(4,'2.00');
                INSERT INTO grosor_tubo VALUES(5,'3.00');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS precio_tipo_tubo (                   .
                    id SERIAL,
                    id_tarifa INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    id_tipo_tubo INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    id_medidas_tipo_tubo INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    id_grosor INTEGER REFERENCES grosor_tubo(id)NOT NULL,
                    coste_grosor NUMERIC (12,2)

                    PRIMARY KEY (id_tarifa,id_tipo_tubo,id_medidas_tipo_tubo,id_grosor)
                );

                    INSERT INTO precio_tipo_tubo VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,100);
                    INSERT INTO precio_tipo_tubo VALUES (2,1,1,1,2,2000);
```

La intención que tengo es, que se genere una vista dinámica que genere las columnas según existan grosores (en este caso 5) de la tabla grosor_tubo y que ponga el coste_grosor en la columna correspondiente de precio_tipo_tubo.

He intentado hacer este crostable:

```
    DO $$
DECLARE 
    select_clause TEXT := '';
    BEGIN
        SELECT FORMAT(
            '
                SELECT * FROM crosstab
                (
                    ''SELECT
            m.id,
            m.id_tarifa,
            m.id_tipo_tubo,
            m.id_medidas_tipo_tubo,
            m.id_grosor,
            ROUND(m.coste_grosor,2) AS coste_grosor
            FROM presu.precio_tipo_tubo AS m
            LEFT JOIN presu.grosor_tubo gt on m.id_grosor=gt.id;
            '',
            ''SELECT id FROM presu.grosor_tubo''
        )
                AS
                (
            id int,
                    id_tarifa int,
                    id_tipo_tubo int,
                    id_medidas_tipo_tubo int,
                    id_grosor int,
                    coste_grosor numeric,
                    %s
                );
            ',
            string_agg(
                FORMAT('%I %s', grosor, 'numeric'), ', '
                ORDER BY id
            )
        ) into select_clause FROM presu.grosor_tubo;
        execute 'create or replace temp view v as ' || select_clause || ' ';    
END $$;

select * from v;
```

Mostrando como resultado: (Solo me muestra el registro 1 insertado en precio_tipo_tubo el registro 2 en la vista dinámica v ni lo muestra)

[image: Resultado pgadmin]

Y la idea, es que la columna, coste_grosor de la vista temporal v, saliera en el contenido de la columna 1.00 creada dinámicamente (ya que de esa linea el id_grosor 1) de la vista temporal v.

La idea, es que genere una vista dinámica para ver e insertar datos de coste_grosor en tantas columnas de grosor como lineas existan en grosor_tubo.

Este problema me surge porque los grosores son dinámicos.

La idea es que se quede una cosa tal que así:

[image: Supuesto de como debería quedar]

Y cada coste_grosor, se pueda introducir y visualizar a través del crosstable dinámico en su columna dinámica generada a partir de grosor_tubo.

Agradezco muchísimo vuestra ayuda.

Att.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma básica de resolverlo es definiendo una vista o consulta dinámica, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT FORMAT('
        SELECT * FROM crosstab
        (
            ''SELECT año, mes, total FROM ventas ORDER BY 1'',
            ''SELECT id FROM meses m''
        )
        AS
        (
            año int,
            %s
        );
    ',
    string_agg(
        FORMAT('%I %s', mes, 'int'), ', '
        ORDER BY id
    )
) into select_clause FROM meses;
```

Como se puede observar, estamos creando dinámicamente la consulta para luego ejecutarla, la parte interesante es el uso de `string_agg()` para concatenar los nombres de las columnas a partir de la propia tabla `meses`. El resultado es una consulta en `select_clause`que deberemos posteriormente ejecutar.

Ver [Demo completa](https://rextester.com/RGI69848)

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho, mil gracias por tu ayuda, tuve que abandonar el tema por otra urgencia de trabajo, y ahora se me plantea este problema pasándolo al ejemplo real. Ojala le pudieras pegar un vistazo. Mil gracias y ya me comentas :)

Comment: Cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida :) gracias maestros :)